# crawler can not extract raw data in Scrapy + python

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am new to `Scrapy` as well as python, I have build crawler using this two.
The crawler is not able to extract the data where spider is following links actually.
It is fetching the empty parent tag where the actual data is there.
I think it is dynamically loaded because `xpath` selector returns `[]` ,even firebug returns full Xpath!

Comment: cool story. Wanna ask anything ?

Comment: I am really stuck at this point ...how can I get that path at run time?

Comment: What have you tried, what your code looks like ? What is it returning, what do you expect it to return ?